# Use Snort 2.9 rules for Snort 2.8.6

Tags: snort, rules, ids, ips

Unfortunately Snort doesn't release rules update 2.8.6 since 2017.
All customer should upgrade to 2.9. But 2.9 is X64 and my OS is Fedora X86.
I need to update my Snort 2.8.6 signatures.
Is there any source to get update or any solution that convert 2.9 rules to 2.8.6?

Comment: I use Suricata instead of snort. It has the X86 version and it supports all snort rules. You can update the rules simply. The main difference is that Suricata uses GPU in IPS mode. It has more advanced IPS mode in general, includes multitasking, and as result, you get high performance allowing to process up to 10Gbe traffic on regular hardware. You can learn more about Suricata features here: https://suricata-ids.org/features/all-features/

Comment: You can't run a 64-bit OS?

Comment: @MichaelHampton : Not possible to use 64-bit OS. It is an embeded X86 OS. I couldn't upgrade it to 64-bit.

Comment: I would have a chat with the device vendor, then.